# Dropbox api - Can you get a hook to a file in dropbox? - PHP

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am investigating dropbox possibilities for integration with another api.

1. Can you get a hook to a file in dropbox.. for example - a url to open up and resave the file with new content.
2. Can you also create files using the dropbox api if permission has previously been granted? Maybe .txt or .xls files etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that dropbox uses a local folder to store files, then some sort of background daemon to monitor said folder for changes. If this is the case, you can simply make changes to files in that folder and the rest should be automatic.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.